# copy previous array values with current push javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

I am trying to push values as condition matches the criteria and push the values to array with last added values merged. but array is getting overwritten by the condition which is matched.

```
   let Event = [];
          if (allCheck['event1']) {
            let ls = Event;
            ls.push('Type1');
          } else if (allCheck['event3']) {
            let ls = Event;
            lS.push('Type2');
          } else if (allCheck['event3']) {
            let ls = Event;
            ne.push('Type3'); 
          }
```

Comment: Can you please share your whole codelines?

Comment: do you actually want to merge drEvent and drEvents arrays after the if checks?

Comment: `let ls = drEvents;` doesn't make a copy of `drEvents`, both the variables are referring to the same array. Also, `ls` is accessible inside that `if` block only.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in what function the above codelines are included...
Anyway to keep the previous array values you do need to define the `devEvent` as global variable.
Meaning, `let drvEvent = [];` should be written outside of the function.

```
let ls, lS, ne; // To access outside of if blocks
if (allCheck['drloadshed']) {
    ls = drEvents;
    ls.push('LOADSHED'); //LOADSHED
} else if (allCheck['drloadshift']) {
    lS = drEvents;
    lS.push('LOADSHIFT'); //both checked
} else if (allCheck['drneutral']) {
    ne = drEvents;
    ne.push('NEUTRAL'); //both checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating clones of `drEvents` to avoid mutating actual array:

```
let ls, lS, ne; 
      if (allCheck['drloadshed']) {
        let ls = [...drEvents];
        ls.push('LOADSHED'); //LOADSHED
      } else if (allCheck['drloadshift']) {
        let lS = [...drEvents];
        lS.push('LOADSHIFT'); //both checked
      } else if (allCheck['drneutral']) {
        let ne = [...drEvents];
        ne.push('NEUTRAL'); //both checked
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variables outside the if conditions.
When you declare with the let keyword it is only accessible inside that block of code, inside the if condition in your case.

```
let drEvent = [];
let ls = [...drEvents];
let lS = [...drEvents];
let ne = [...drEvents];
      if (allCheck['drloadshed']) {
        ls.push('LOADSHED'); //LOADSHED
      } else if (allCheck['drloadshift']) {
        lS.push('LOADSHIFT'); //both checked
      } else if (allCheck['drneutral']) {
        ne.push('NEUTRAL'); //both checked
      }
```

To avoid overwriting the same array you can use the spread operator (...) to create a copy of the same array.
To search more about why this happens you can search for differences between pass by value and pass by reference (primitive data types and reference data types).